Facing error while making iOS build in xcode 15.2
`Failed to build iOS app in Xcode 15.2. I am facing this errors ("ld: Undefined symbols" and "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"). Before updating pods my project is running fine but after updating pods i am facing these errors. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?
I have tried to remove pods and installed it again.
Deleted archive and drived data folder.
Clean project.
Restart Xcode and system.`
Podfile Image
Error Image

Looks like the error is coming from GoogleMobileAds library. Did you update it's version? Please share your podfile.

this is pod file.
use_frameworks!
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'iOSDropDown'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.14.0'
end

Yes i had updated all of pods , After update this error is occured.
I have attached podfile and error image in question.

What happens if you downgrade the version of Google Mobile Ads?

Basically problem were with the latest version of 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'  (11.6.0), to use latest version of 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'  Xcode 15.3 or latest is required.
In my case i have Xcode 15.2 so i have downgrade 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' version from "11.6.0" to "11.5.0".

Basically problem were with the latest version of 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'  (11.6.0), to use latest version of 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'  Xcode 15.3 or latest is required.
In my case i have Xcode 15.2 so i have downgrade 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' version from "11.6.0" to "11.5.0".
